# Moving to - correct expression for context

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

I have three questions concerning my second sentence:

- Is "moving to" the correct expression for my informal email? If not, which one should I use?
- Is "pleased" the appropriate word for my context? Any other options?
- How about the preposition after "turned to"? Should it be about / for?

Hi Jo,

Great to hear from you! How are you? I'm fine.
Lately, I've been having a lot of fun since I joined a gym.

Moving to your current situation, I'm pleased that you turned to me about / for your problems with your parents.

Comment: Simo, we don't do proofreading on this site or attempting to improve people's writing. If you have a particular question about grammar or idiom, you should say so. Even better, tell us what efforts you have made to find the answer yourself.

Comment: Hi Ronald, thanks for your message. However, my final aim was not to get better  my own writing. I was just trying to improve my English skills and solve my doubts in regard to these topics.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "moving to" sounds as if it should be in the middle of a long discussion, to signal a change of focus. In a short informal email, it sounds out of place. Instead you could say "As to...", or just "About...".

I think "happy" would fit as well as "pleased".

I think "asked me" would fit better than "turned to me", if the context is just that someone asked for advice.